# How to change the cell height after putting a collection view into a table view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm trying to put some images with horizontal scrolling in a tableview cell, so I use a collectionview, I put it into the cell, and everything works except the cell height. I've chosen the cell height to custom in storyboard, and changed the cell height with code too, but it still doesn't work. I'm a rookie, I can't find where the problem is, please help me, thank you guys!
[1.I want to change the cell height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE3oY.png)
[2.Stroyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3uYB.png)

```
class HomePageTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var ImageArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    ImageArray = ["Calendar.png","Calendar.png","Calendar.png","Calendar.png","Calendar.png"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return ImageArray.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BannerCell") as! BannerTableViewCell

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }   
}
   extension HomePageTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, 
   UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return ImageArray.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    ->  UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BannerCollection", for: indexPath) as! BannerCollectionCollectionViewCell

        cell.BannerImage.image = UIImage(named: ImageArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell


     }
 }
```

Comment: TableViews have a function called `heightForRowAt: IndexPath` Call that function and set the height in there. And CollectionViews have something called a `flowLayout` that you can mess with if you have multiple cells in the collection.

Comment: There is no cells in your code , it's a separate tableView & collectionView

Comment: Where is your collectionview?  Did you add it to your BannerCell custom tableview cell?  Where did you set the datasource and delegate for your collectionview?

Comment: @Shawn  I created two classes named BannerTableViewCell and BannerCollectionViewCell, and set the table view cell identifier with  "BannerCell", and collection reusable view identifier is "BannerCollection" in storyboard, the datasource and delegata have connected to the tableview controller.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the collectionviewcell size such as the following:

```
extension HomePageTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        // Return the cell size
        let cellSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.width * (ratioToUse))
        return cellSize
    }
}
```

I've done something similar where I'm using a collectionview to scroll horizontally but I'm using the full width for each cell and calculating the aspectratio.  However, you'll need to modify this for the size you want.

I had to do some tricks elsewhere to size the collectionview itself as well.

I would try this first then, if you're still having problems, post an image of what it looks like.

Update #2:

If you are using AutoLayout, you shouldn't need to do this but you can set the height yourself using the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    <#code#>
}
```

Update #3:

I just some testing with this.  You should put a height constraint on your collectionview and that should make the tableviewcell resize appropriately.  You shouldn't need "heightForRowAt" as I mentioned above.  AutoLayout should handle this for you.

Comment: Firstly thank your help！ But what I want to change is the tableview cell, not the collectionview, I tried your code, it changed my collectionview cell, the tableview cell didn’t change.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?  Typically, I use autolayout and specify         tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension / tableView.estimatedRowHeight = XXX.  The tableviewcell should size itself correctly if your constraints are right.

Comment: yeah，I’ve used Autolayout to the collectionview and imageview， and used that code too, but still nothing.

Comment: @JesseS, can you show a screenshot of what you're getting?

Comment: I've put the image link in the question, thanks for your help again!

Comment: @JesseS, what constraints do you have set on the collectionview inside of your tableview cell?

Comment: @JesseS, try putting a height constraint on the collectionview in your tableviewcell class.  See if that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the content mode of the UIImageView to aspect fit. It might work.